# How to find valid or null rows for each column in multiple csv files in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have various .csv files. Each file has multiple columns. I want to do a quality check that for a particular column, how many rows have valid values and how many are null..something like if a row has some value, return Valid or the value, otherwise return null or FALSE. I want to do it for all the columns, for all the files in R. In the end, I want a log file as well.

My sample data:

```
D_T  Temp (°C)  Press (Pa)  ...
2021-03-01 00:00:00+00  28  1018  ...
2021-03-02 00:00:00+00  27  1017  ...
2021-03-03 00:00:00+00  28  1019  ...
..
..
```

Answer (score 0):

first install package

```
install.packages("readr")
```

and then

paste the code and run it

```
check_column <- function(df, column) {
  valid_values <- !is.na(df[[column]])
  num_valid <- sum(valid_values)
  num_null <- nrow(df) - num_valid
  return(c(num_valid, num_null))
}

    Read the CSV file
    df <- read_csv("data.csv")
    

    for (column in names(df)) {
      results <- check_column(df, column)
      print(paste(column, ": ", results[1], " valid, ", results[2], " null"))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I have various files and I want to run QC on all the files at once and get output as per the file name, could you please help me by modifying the code to process multiple files.

Comment: please use shell to run it

Comment: Could you please explain. I have never used shell to run R scripts. And by running it through shell, will it be able to read and process all files. I want to save a log file of this